# GMail not autolinking URLs in Firefox 3.6

Tags: firefox, gmail, url, hyperlink

I've noticed that when I compose an email in GMail using Firefox 3.6, it no longer automatically converts URLs into hyperlinks.

On the odd occasion that I used IE, it did the automatic conversion as I would like.

I'm sure this used to work. Is there a way to restore the auto-linking behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know. But if you select the link text and click in hyperlink icon the hyperlink will be created there.

Comment: Sure, but I want it to do this automatically for me.